# Error while working with MutableList

Tags: python, list, mutable

I'm working on a simple size() method while working with Mutablelists and I keep getting the following error:

```
>>> xs = MutableList
>>> xs
<class __main__.MutableList at 0x02AC6848>
>>> xs.size()

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    xs
.size()
  File "C:\Users\safim\Desktop\Python HW 4\a3_1.py", line 59, in size
    for x in self :
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

The code I used was:

```
result = 0
for x in self :
  result + 1
return result
```

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Where is `MutableList` coming from?

Comment: what do you mean? @kindall

Comment: `MutableList` isn't a type built into Python. What is it and where did you get it?

Comment: Is `MutableList` something you created?

Comment: Well, this is part of our assignment is working with "MutableLists". Here's what they were defined as `class MutableList :

  """Mutable lists. We maintain a pointer 'front' to a list and use DELEGATION
  for read-only operations. Operations that change the list are implemented by
  explicit pointer manipulations that update 'front' or self.tail for the relevant
  node in the list.
  """

  def __init__ (self) :
    self.front = EmptyList()`    @kindall

Comment: So you are trying to implement this `MutableList` as an assignment?

Comment: yes i am @skyline75489

Comment: Well...what is `EmptyList()` then?

Comment: Is this all the code out there? What's the task?

Answer (score 0):

`xs` is the same object as `MutableList`, because you made it so:

```
xs = MutableList
```

The message printed even tells you this:

```
<class __main__.MutableList at 0x02AC6848>
```

As it says, `xs` is the class, not an instance of that class.

You can't call `MutableList.size()` (which is what you're trying to do, because `xs` and `MutableList` are the same thing) because that doesn't tell it what instance you want to use.

Did you mean to instantiate a `MutableList`? If so:

```
xs = MutableList()
```

Your other code won't work either, since `result + 1` adds 1 to `result` and then throws away that number (you never assign it to a variable). Most likely you mean `result += 1`.

Comment: Sorry, I was forgetting to do MutableList() my real problem is the error "TypeError: iteration over non-sequence"